# Its printing $image but inserting null into DB

Tags: image, mongodb, set

Ok I am using Mongodb
and I have the following code

```
$image = $chnl->getElementsByTagName("image");

                    foreach($image as $img){
                        $imgs = $img->getElementsByTagName("url");
                        $image = $imgs->item(0)->nodeValue;
                        print $image;
                        $collection = $fetch->db->shows;
                        $collection->update(
                        array( "_id"=> new MongoId($d["_id"])),
                        array( '$set' => array("image"=>$image) )
                    );
                    }
```

it is printing the image URL, but when I try to add it to the mongodb buy $set it is inserting null into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your writing in PHP.

The $image variable you have there is an array. So the foreach block will split each element with a tag of $image as the $img variable. Line #4 appears to be re-assigning the $image array.

Try changing the $image within your loop too a new variable name.

Comment: What is the output of the $image variable? What datatype is it?

Comment: Meaning a string. Try adding quotes like this array( '$set' => array("image"=>"$image") )